# I can't access Tomcat 7 manager when Tomcat is running through IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 12

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I am trying to access tomcat manager by using

```
http://localhost:8080/manager
```

but I am always denied the entrance after I enter the password.
I get the following message :

> 403 Access Denied
>
> You are not authorized to view this page.
>
> If you have already configured the Manager application to allow access
>   and you have used your browsers back button, used a saved book-mark or
>   similar then you may have triggered the cross-site request forgery
>   (CSRF) protection that has been enabled for the HTML interface of the
>   Manager application. You will need to reset this protection by
>   returning to the main Manager page. Once you return to this page, you
>   will be able to continue using the Manager appliction's HTML interface
>   normally. If you continue to see this access denied message, check
>   that you have the necessary permissions to access this application.
>
> If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the
>   file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must
>   contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.
>
> For example, to add the manager-gui role to a user named tomcat with a
>   password of s3cret, add the following to the config file listed above.
>
> Note that for Tomcat 7
>   onwards, the roles required to use the manager application were
>   changed from the single manager role to the following four roles. You
>   will need to assign the role(s) required for the functionality you
>   wish to access.
>
> manager-gui - allows access to the HTML GUI and the status pages
>   manager-script - allows access to the text interface and the status
>   pages manager-jmx - allows access to the JMX proxy and the status
>   pages manager-status - allows access to the status pages only The HTML
>   interface is protected against CSRF but the text and JMX interfaces
>   are not. To maintain the CSRF protection:
>
> Users with the manager-gui role should not be granted either the
>   manager-script or manager-jmx roles. If the text or jmx interfaces are
>   accessed through a browser (e.g. for testing since these interfaces
>   are intended for tools not humans) then the browser must be closed
>   afterwards to terminate the session. For more information - please see
>   the Manager App HOW-TO.

Here is my tomcat-users.xml :

```
<tomcat-users> 
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="admin-gui,standard,manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I am running tomcat 7 through intellij idea 12 ultimate.
I am using Mountain Lion operating system.
Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me with Tomcat 7/IDEA 12. Make sure you've [configured deployment of the default applications](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/3721/20130131181624.png). Not sure you are allowed to have multiple users with the same name and different passwords/roles. I tested it with just one user: `<user username="serge" password="serge" roles="manager-gui"/>`.

Comment: I've ticked the option you show and I've added another user but the problem remains.

Comment: Try a clean Tomcat 7 installation with the only change to `tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: Crazy coder : Do you run tomcat on a unix system?

Comment: No, I tested on Windows, however I don't think it's specific to the OS.

Comment: When I run Tomcat 7 with its own startup.sh script I can see the tomcat homepage but I still cannot access the manager.When Tomcat 7 is deployed using intellij's 'catalins.sh run' command I can't even see this home page.

Comment: skiabox would you please chose my answer as the Answer to your question?

Answer (score 16):

I edited two files : **server.xml** & **tomcat-users.xml**

**STEP 1** : I added this line to the **server.xml**, this line must be added under **Engine** context same as the picture:

`<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />`

here you can see the picture :

[image]

**STEP 2** : then I edited **tomcat-users.xml** and added the lines below :

```
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a 
  comment and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget
  to remove <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-script "/> 

</tomcat-users>
```

**NOTE : I recommend you to copy and paste my text and replace it by yours**

Restart tomcat and you're ready to go !

Comment: Part of your answer was helpful to me, but would you mind explaining what does `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />` do?

Comment: +0 I'm pretty sure that the `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />` part is unnecessary. [user33296337's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627176/i-cant-access-tomcat-7-manager-when-tomcat-is-running-through-intellij-idea-ult#21889950) is better.

Answer (score 3):

You need both privilege access, `manager-gui` and `manager-script`, for a role.

Example:

```
    <!-- you need both roles, manager-gui & manager-script for user-->
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="tomcat" 
      password="blabla" roles="manager-gui,manager-script "/> 
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by adding CATALINA_HOME variable and giving it the value /Library/Tomcat at the following field :

Run --> Edit Configurations --> Tomcat Server --> Tomcat 7.0 --> 'Startup/Connection' Tab -->Environment Variables

Comment: This configuration is not needed, normally it's defined when [adding a server in IDEA](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/4048/20130131190733.png) and is  [passed automatically on start](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5104/20130131190848.png).

Comment: I can confirm the [same output on Mac](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/Screenshots/92ohp1tbxa7b.png), but `/manager` app still [works just fine without this change](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/Screenshots/qtettkgnfejj.png).

Comment: The only difference that I can see is that I have created a link with the name /Library/Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I solved it by changing the owner of the configuration files to tomcat, they were owned by root for some reason.

```
cd /etc/tomcat
chown tomcat:group *
#restart tomcat service
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with my tomcat. I realized that some folders like **lib**,  **conf** under tomcat didn't have executable(x) permissions. When I gave executable permissions to the folders, problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you are in your tomcat folder as $TOMCAT_HOME

**Step1:**

on $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/**tomcat-users.xml** add the following line

```
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```

with in:

```
   <tomcat-users.......

   </tomcat-users>
```

So it will looks like:

```
<tomcat-users.......
      <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Step2:**

and on $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/**context.xml** :
delete the following tag:

```
<Valve className=......
```

So it will be as:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
-->
</Context>
```

**Final:**

restart your tomcat

and you can find more details on [Apache Tomcat 8 Manager App](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

It actually helped me.
You should try with a better(non guessable) username not like "Admin"

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="TomcatAdmin" password="secpa55wd" roles="manager-gui"/>
```