# Unable to access Tomcat 8 manager when Tomcat is running through Apache Server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Apache server has been put infront of tomcat to redirect the request from 80 port to 8080 port through mod_proxy connector. 
The problem I am facing is that I can't access the manager page of tomcat to deploy war file.

I have read a lot and just got one similar question on SO [SO SIMILAIR LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627176/i-cant-access-tomcat-7-manager-when-tomcat-is-running-through-intellij-idea-ult)

I tried the changes asked by the answerer there but no result.  I am still getting the NOT FOUND error on accesssing **localhost:8080/manager/html**

**What is the issue?**

**How to access the manager page to deploy war file of the project?**

**What should be the new url for manager page?**

**IS THERE ANYWAY TO ACCESS MANAGER PAGE ON 80 PORT OF APACHE?**

APACHE Version => 2.4

TOMCAT Version => 8

Comment: ... if you put apache in front of it, wouldn't the url be localhost/manager/html because you now access it through port 80?

Comment: than how will I access it?

Comment: In a browser with the url http://localhost/manager/html :/

Comment: its a giving a error web page not available

Comment: apache  version is 2.x and tomcat Is 8. Yes previously I was able to accces manager page before the apache server was  been installed

Comment: before the installation of apache server it was accessible outside within network  also as it was binded through a local ip

Comment: Anythng more you want to know?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the proxy configuration of Apache 2.4 and format it as code to make it readable. It would be better to add the details you added afterwards in the comments and move them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

> In addition to the password restrictions the Manager web application
>   could be restricted by the remote IP address or host by adding a
>   RemoteAddrValve or RemoteHostValve. See valves documentation for
>   details.